# Python: How to use dictionary to operate on user input?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

```
def calculator():
    print("When prompted to enter a symbol, enter:\n'+' to add,\n'-' to subtract,\n'*' to multiply,\n'/' to divide,\n'^' to calculate powers,")
    print("',\n'=' to get the answer.")
    again = None
    while again != "x":
        answer = float(input("\nEnter number: "))
        while 1 == 1:
            symbol = input("Enter symbol: ")
            if symbol == "=":
                print("\nThe answer is ", answer, ".", sep = "")
                again = input("\nEnter 'a' to use the calculator again and 'x' to exit: ")
                break
            number = float(input("Enter number: "))
            #trying to use a dictionary instead of "if" statements present in docstring
            dictionary = {"+": answer += number, "-": answer -= number, "*": answer *= number, "/": answer /= number, "^": answer **= number}
            dictionary[symbol]
            """if symbol == "+":
                answer += number
            if symbol == "-":
                answer -= number
            if symbol == "*":
                answer *= number
            if symbol == "/":
                answer /= number
            if symbol == "^":
                answer **= number"""
```

I felt having a bunch of "if" statements would be WET code (as seen in the docstring). I want to operate on the number based on the user inputted symbol, but it says "invalid syntax" even if i only keep the value of the symbol as the operator in the dictionary (i.e., only "+": +, "-": -, etc. in the dictionary)

**Edit:**
I want less code, so please do not tell me to make a function to call.

Comment: Have a look at the [`operator` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html), which provides common operators as functions.

Comment: @Evert thx that worked :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to define functions for your operations and store them in a dictionary. Something like:

```
def plus (a, b):
  return a+b

def minus (a, b):
  return a-b

my_dict = {"+" : plus, "-" : minus}

answer = my_dict[symbol](answer, number)
```

At least this should give you an idea.

Comment: I thought of making functions, but that would result in an even greater amount of code (sorry, let me edit my question to be more specific).